# j2store plugin tag is not working in bt content slider

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, articles, css

I have used J2Store my for website. All articles are working and add to cart button appears but in "BT content slider" module I have displayed articles in 3 columns and inside articles  I just added images with "price" and "add to cart" tags. But the module is showing text instead of buttons.

And secondly how to customize the "Add to cart" button with custom css as i have included my custom css class in J2Store layout option but it's not working, also unable to override the default button with my custom css stylesheet.

P.S. I have inspected the relevant classes of button with firebug and included `!important` in my css properties. Nothing happened..!!

Comment: Without any code to refer to, it's unlikely that you'll get any help here, as well, since it's a 3rd party plugin, that's probably the best place to start anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, make sure you enable the "Prepare Content" option in your module. You'll find the setting under the "Options" tab. This will allow plugins to process the contents of the module before output.

[image: Module settings: Prepare content]

In order to style the <kbd>Add to cart</kbd> button, you should be able to target it with this CSS selector:

```
input#addtoCartBtn {
   color: red; // Add your CSS style here
}
```

Only add `!important` if necessary. Make sure your custom CSS file is loaded properly.